# Split a numeric dataframe into all possible combinations of 2 columns in R

Tags: r, multiple-columns, correlation

I am trying to split the columns of a dataframe to find pmcc of all possible combinations of (two)columns from a dataframe containing n columns, e.g. in this case, with 3 columns
  Length Diameter Height

0.455    0.365  0.095
0.350    0.265  0.090
0.530    0.420  0.135
0.440    0.365  0.125
0.330    0.255  0.22

here I have to find pmcc for all combinations, eg, (length, diameter), (diameter, height), etc.
Any help!
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data.frame(z = rnorm(100, 2), y = rnorm(100, 4), x = rnorm(100, 6)) -> frame
combn(colnames(frame), 2) -> combos
apply(combos, 2, function(x) cor(frame[,x[1]], frame[,x[2]]))
```