# R: Split a dataframe into n partition and recombine them in all possible combination of partitions

Tags: r, dataframe, combn

I have dataframe with 6 columns and I want to partition them into 3 parts each with 2 columns. I want to recombine partitions in all possible combinations to create 7 new dataframes

```
part1,part2,part3
part1,par2
part1,part3
part2,part3
part1
part2
part3
```

I modified this solution a bit to recombine them [Split a dataframe into all possible combinations of dataframes by 3 columns in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50614023/split-a-dataframe-into-all-possible-combinations-of-dataframes-by-3-columns-in-r)

```
>frame <- data.frame(id = letters[seq( from = 1, to = 10 )], a = rnorm(10, 4), b = rnorm(10, 6), c=rnorm(10, 5), d = rnorm(10, 2),e=rnorm(10, 5), f = rnorm(10, 2))

> frame
   id        a        b        c         d        e          f
1   a 6.322845 5.828619 5.465636 2.7658092 6.522706  1.4896078
2   b 2.352437 5.521230 6.555715 0.6612871 5.288508  2.4837969
3   c 2.790967 9.253197 3.724231 2.9954273 4.887744  1.3020424
4   d 2.017975 6.038846 4.540511 1.7989492 6.059974 -0.2463154
5   e 4.004463 4.384898 5.341084 1.9528288 4.186449  1.0823939
6   f 2.600336 6.562758 5.708489 2.1142707 6.769220  1.7942291
7   g 3.850400 7.231973 4.918542 3.3562489 6.090841  1.4202527
8   h 2.932744 6.377516 5.518261 1.7423230 4.422915  1.8789437
9   i 5.135185 5.218992 4.710196 1.1878825 5.421876  0.8455756
10  j 5.188278 7.233590 6.303500 0.3868047 4.390973  1.6997801 

>m <- seq(3) 
>j <-function(m){lapply(as.data.frame(combn(ncol(frame) - 1, m)), function(idx) frame[, c(1, idx + 1)])}

>lapply(m, function(m) j(m))
```

This would create all combinations by shuffling all columns. I do not want combinations of columns, but combinations of partitions. How can I achieve that?

Comment: how are your partitions defined in the case of your sample `frame`?

Comment: The partitions are created in order means the first two columns form the first partition, the next two form the second etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one try:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

# Assign a partition to be used here
# (Updated from OP's clarification about pttns & @bouncyball's comment)
pttn <- split(names(frame)[-1], rep(1:3, each = 2))

# Create combinations of partitioned columns
do.call(c, lapply(seq_along(pttn), combn, x = pttn, simplify = FALSE)) %>% 
   map(~ frame %>% select(reduce(.x, c)))
```

The first line with do.call creates all combinations of 'partitions', or the partitioned column names. If you want to preserve `ID` column, you can use `id, reduce(.x, c)` instead of `reduce(.x, c)`

Comment: nice! I would just change `pttn` to be `pttn <- split(names(frame)[-1], rep(1:3, each = 2))`

Comment: Thanks! The original answer was written before OP clarified what partitions should be used :) I've updated the answer accordingly!

Comment: I know we are not supposed to use the comments for this, but this answer is amazing... a bit magical even.

Comment: Perfect soution. Thank you!

Comment: How can I generate each combination on the fly during the data process rather than throwing all combinations as output at a time? This will be useful for large datasets. Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify? Are you looking for something like `frame %>% select(pttn[[1]])` ?

Comment: I want to process each one of the 7 outputs further, one at a time. I do not want all 7 outputs generated at the same time. It will be helpful to reduce the memory usage if I can generate each of the 7 outputs, one at a time, and process it. I hope I made it clear. Thank you once again

Comment: frame %>% select(pttn[[1]]) works partially, but it is priting same solution 7 times.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution using `purrr::map()` and some data wrangling to long/wide. Might not be the most efficient or elagant solution, but it does its job.

```r
library(tidyverse)

# sample data
frame <- data.frame(
  id = letters[seq( from = 1, to = 10 )], a = rnorm(10, 4), b = rnorm(10, 6), c=rnorm(10, 5), 
  d = rnorm(10, 2),e=rnorm(10, 5), f = rnorm(10, 2))

# list of possible combinations 
list_of_combinations <- list(
  c(1), 
  c(2),
  c(3),
  c(1,2),
  c(1,3),
  c(2,3),
  c(1,2,3)
)

# data in long format and a category variable (for each "chunk")
df_long <- frame %>% pivot_longer(-id) %>% 
  mutate(
    cat = case_when(
      (name %in% c("a", "b")) ~ 1L, 
      (name %in% c("c", "d")) ~ 2L, 
      (name %in% c("e", "f")) ~ 3L)
  )
df_long
#> # A tibble: 60 x 4
#>    id    name   value   cat
#>    <chr> <chr>  <dbl> <int>
#>  1 a     a      3.93      1
#>  2 a     b      4.66      1
#>  3 a     c      2.78      2
#>  4 a     d      2.35      2
#>  5 a     e      5.93      3
#>  6 a     f     -0.500     3
#>  7 b     a      5.11      1
#>  8 b     b      5.37      1
#>  9 b     c      4.61      2
#> 10 b     d      3.58      2
#> # … with 50 more rows

# map list to generate a list of each combination and then map it back into wide format 
final_list_of_dfs <- list_of_combinations %>% map( ~ df_long %>% filter(cat %in% .x)) %>% 
  map(~ .x %>% select(-cat) %>% pivot_wider(names_from = "name", values_from = "value"))
glimpse(final_list_of_dfs)
#> List of 7
#>  $ : tibble [10 × 3] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
#>   ..$ id: chr [1:10] "a" "b" "c" "d" ...
#>   ..$ a : num [1:10] 3.93 5.11 4.16 2.59 2.69 ...
#>   ..$ b : num [1:10] 4.66 5.37 3.26 5.52 6.29 ...
#>  $ : tibble [10 × 3] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
#>   ..$ id: chr [1:10] "a" "b" "c" "d" ...
#>   ..$ c : num [1:10] 2.78 4.61 3.8 3.06 4.68 ...
#>   ..$ d : num [1:10] 2.353 3.579 0.744 1.582 3.377 ...
#>  $ : tibble [10 × 3] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
#>   ..$ id: chr [1:10] "a" "b" "c" "d" ...
#>   ..$ e : num [1:10] 5.93 3.89 5.43 3.88 5.51 ...
#>   ..$ f : num [1:10] -0.5 0.941 3.703 2.035 0.611 ...
#>  $ : tibble [10 × 5] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
#>   ..$ id: chr [1:10] "a" "b" "c" "d" ...
#>   ..$ a : num [1:10] 3.93 5.11 4.16 2.59 2.69 ...
#>   ..$ b : num [1:10] 4.66 5.37 3.26 5.52 6.29 ...
#>   ..$ c : num [1:10] 2.78 4.61 3.8 3.06 4.68 ...
#>   ..$ d : num [1:10] 2.353 3.579 0.744 1.582 3.377 ...
#>  $ : tibble [10 × 5] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
#>   ..$ id: chr [1:10] "a" "b" "c" "d" ...
#>   ..$ a : num [1:10] 3.93 5.11 4.16 2.59 2.69 ...
#>   ..$ b : num [1:10] 4.66 5.37 3.26 5.52 6.29 ...
#>   ..$ e : num [1:10] 5.93 3.89 5.43 3.88 5.51 ...
#>   ..$ f : num [1:10] -0.5 0.941 3.703 2.035 0.611 ...
#>  $ : tibble [10 × 5] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
#>   ..$ id: chr [1:10] "a" "b" "c" "d" ...
#>   ..$ c : num [1:10] 2.78 4.61 3.8 3.06 4.68 ...
#>   ..$ d : num [1:10] 2.353 3.579 0.744 1.582 3.377 ...
#>   ..$ e : num [1:10] 5.93 3.89 5.43 3.88 5.51 ...
#>   ..$ f : num [1:10] -0.5 0.941 3.703 2.035 0.611 ...
#>  $ : tibble [10 × 7] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
#>   ..$ id: chr [1:10] "a" "b" "c" "d" ...
#>   ..$ a : num [1:10] 3.93 5.11 4.16 2.59 2.69 ...
#>   ..$ b : num [1:10] 4.66 5.37 3.26 5.52 6.29 ...
#>   ..$ c : num [1:10] 2.78 4.61 3.8 3.06 4.68 ...
#>   ..$ d : num [1:10] 2.353 3.579 0.744 1.582 3.377 ...
#>   ..$ e : num [1:10] 5.93 3.89 5.43 3.88 5.51 ...
#>   ..$ f : num [1:10] -0.5 0.941 3.703 2.035 0.611 ...
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>